# Trying to find all .txt files from directory and sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, os.path, listdir

This code is showing access denied issue. I dont want to use os.walk function to fetch all files and directories i want to fetch without that.

```
import os
import sys
test_path = "/"

def print_directory_contents(dir_path):
   for child in os.listdir(dir_path):
      path = os.path.join(dir_path, child)
      if os.path.isdir(path):
         print("FOLDER: " + "\t" + path)
         print_directory_contents(path)
      else:
        print("FILE: " + "\t" + path)

print_directory_contents(test_path)
```

---

```
       Output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 33, in <module>
print_directory_contents(test_path)
  File "a.py", line 26, in print_directory_contents
print_directory_contents(path)
  File "a.py", line 26, in print_directory_contents
print_directory_contents(path)
  File "a.py", line 22, in print_directory_contents
for child in os.listdir(dir_path):
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pulse-
  PKdhtXMmr18n'
```

Comment: Try running your program with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that you aren't using `os.walk`, it's that you simply don't have the permissions required to list the contents of the */tmp/pulse-
  PKdhtXMmr18n* directory.

Comment: so any other option?because i don't having root access.

Comment: @abhi09sep There is. You could just catch the error and handle it. Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525677/4909087).

Answer (score 1):

Either use "sudo" unless your code doesn't write anything (you may kill your system with buggy code), or surround the relevant code with `try: ... except PermissionError` with appropriate error logging.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using / as path, i assume you are using Linux.
You should add a print to your script to  display the path that is causing the issue.If it is an important Linux folder, this error is normal if the script doesn't have root privileges, because access to such folders is limited.(and there are several directrices like these,/root for example)